# How to prepare a regex that will escape partial digits while matching?

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I'm using `pcre_exec()` to compile regular expressions.

I want to match the string having number with 3 digits followed by "-", but it should not match if the number is prefixed with one or more digits.
e.g.

```
345- => match and matches text => (345-)
:546- = match and matches text => (546-)
 123- = match and matches text => (123-)
2355- = Should not match as 355- is prefixed with "2" digit.
```

I tried `^([\\s|:]*)([0-7]\\d{2})-` but it is not working.

Comment: Note: amongst other valuable tools: http://regexr.com/3a394

Comment: @xtofl the thing is with a negated character class that it's not zero-width. Which means `345-` doesn't get matched while it should. If you have a JS background, I would suggest to read this [article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) since JS doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use look-behind to assert that the previous character is not digit:

```
(?<!\d)([0-7]\d{2})-
```